# Securing Java Sockets

Tags: java, security, sockets, netty

I've written a Java application which involves a server and multiple client instances. All the clients connect to the server from multiple locations. **This needs to be compatible with Netty as that is what I use to handle my connections.** I realised that this system could potentially become compromised. Is there a secure way to make sure that the server is talking to who they want to be talking to?

I thought of possibly using pairing keys which would be stored on each end, if the key matched then the server would allow the connection but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use SSL such as the SSLSocketFactory. You will have to have a look at JSSE, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/samples/index.html) is a tutorial in case you are curious.

Taken from the linked tutorial:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory =
        (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket =
        (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("www.verisign.com", 443);

        /*
         * send http request
         *
         * Before any application data is sent or received, the
         * SSL socket will do SSL handshaking first to set up
         * the security attributes.
         *
         * SSL handshaking can be initiated by either flushing data
         * down the pipe, or by starting the handshaking by hand.
         *
         * Handshaking is started manually in this example because
         * PrintWriter catches all IOExceptions (including
         * SSLExceptions), sets an internal error flag, and then
         * returns without rethrowing the exception.
         *
         * Unfortunately, this means any error messages are lost,
         * which caused lots of confusion for others using this
         * code.  The only way to tell there was an error is to call
         * PrintWriter.checkError().
         */
        socket.startHandshake();
```

This shows how a client might implement SSL. Note, this is only part of what is a pretty complicated client/server interaction in Java.

UPDATE:

For examples on how to do this with Netty, see their examples at their github:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver

Comment: Any idea how I would do this in Netty?
Edit: Also is this just for website stuff? Not sure if I can use in my Server & Client situation.

Comment: @iKeirNez Yes, they have some examples on their github on how to serve SSL. Please see updated link.

Comment: Okay, the examples seem to be for web pages, will this work in my situation?

Comment: @iKeirNez you can generally use JSSE for securing any sockets using SSL. The Netty examples are only for WebSockets, so if you are not dealing with http then I would just use the JSSE examples.

Comment: Ah, I need it to work with Netty and as far as I can tell, the JSSE stuff isn't going to be compatible with it. Sorry I'm a bit new to Sockets.

Comment: I found a Netty example that I may be able to use. Going to start implementing this, will let you know how it goes. Thanks again! http://netty.io/5.0/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html